# Using audio_play_sound() in a if statement GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

I am trying to use the command:

```
audio_play_sound()
```

I am trying to insert it into this piece of code, so that when the player jumps, a sound plays.

```
if (key_jump) && (jumps > 0)
{
     jumps -=1;
     vsp = -jumpspeed;
}
```

Code that causes problem:

```
if (key_jump) && (jumps > 0)
{
     jumps -=1;
     vsp = -jumpspeed;
     audio_play_sound(snd_jump)
}
```

Simply inserting the line into the if statement does not work, and gives the error WRONG NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS IN FUNCTION. This is rather confusing, perhaps I am using the wrong command? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with code that reproduces the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done that big boi

Comment: Now: what have you done to solve this? What are your results? No one wants to debug your program for you. Have you done a basic web search? Have you studied the API docs? Hint: https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/game%20assets/sounds/audio_play_sound.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stated in the error, you're providing the wrong number of arguments to the `audo_play_sound` function.

from the [docs](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/game%20assets/sounds/audio_play_sound.html)

```
audio_play_sound(index, priority, loop);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the person above states your answer is `audio_play_sound(snd_jump, 1, false)`.